# Send messages to an Android Wearable

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I want to send a messsage to two different Android Smart-Watches.
On the mobile side the `Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage` gets called and the `sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()` is true, so the sending of the message should work.
The problem now is, that the `onMessageReceived` method of the `MyWearableListenerService` never receives a message. What am I doing wrong?
This is the code I'm using:

MainActivity of the Android App.

The left/right methods are sending the messages

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private static final String TAG_CONNECTION = "Connection";
private static final String TAG_NODES = "Nodes";

private static final String START_ACTIVITY_PATH = "/start_MainActivity";

private String leftWatch;
private String rightWatch;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Setting up the Wearable API Client
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Connection established");

                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Connection suspended");
                }
            })
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    // Find the connected watches and store their UUIDs to distinguish at a later moment
    Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult getConnectedNodesResult) {
            List<Node> nodes = getConnectedNodesResult.getNodes();

            if (nodes.isEmpty()) {
                Log.e(TAG_NODES, "No Nodes found");
                return;
            }

            rightWatch = nodes.get(0).getId();
            Log.e(TAG_NODES,"Node is nearby: "+nodes.get(0).isNearby());
            Log.e(TAG_NODES, rightWatch);
            leftWatch = nodes.get(1).getId();
            Log.e(TAG_NODES,"Node is nearby: "+nodes.get(1).isNearby());
            Log.e(TAG_NODES, leftWatch);

        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    // Executed upon failed connection to Wearable API
    // e.g. when Android Wear App is missing

    Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Connection failed");
}

public void left(View view) {
    Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Trying to send message to: " + leftWatch);

    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, leftWatch, START_ACTIVITY_PATH, new byte[0]).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
            if (!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Failed to send message with status code: "
                        + sendMessageResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                return;
            }
            Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Message successfully sent");
        }
    });

}

public void right(View view) {
    Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Trying to send message to: " + rightWatch);

    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, rightWatch, START_ACTIVITY_PATH, new byte[0]).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
            if (!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Failed to send message with status code: "
                        + sendMessageResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                return;
            }
            Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Message successfully sent");
        }
    });


}

public void both(View view) {

    Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Trying to send message to: All currently connected watches");

    Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult getConnectedNodesResult) {
            List<Node> nodes = getConnectedNodesResult.getNodes();

            for (final Node node : nodes) {
                Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), START_ACTIVITY_PATH, new byte[0]).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                        if (!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Failed to send message with status code: "
                                    + sendMessageResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                            return;
                        }
                        Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Message successfully sent to: " + node.getId());
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

MyWearableListenerService

```
public class MyWearableListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

private static final String TAG_SIGNAL = "Signal";
private static final String TAG_CONNECTION = "Connection";
private static final String START_ACTIVITY_PATH = "/start_MainActivity";


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

    Log.e(TAG_SIGNAL, "Message received: " + messageEvent.getPath());

    if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(START_ACTIVITY_PATH)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainWearActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);


}


@Override
public void onPeerConnected(Node node) {
    Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Peer connected: " + node.getId());
    super.onPeerConnected(node);
}

@Override
public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node) {
    Log.e(TAG_CONNECTION, "Peer disconnected: " + node.getId());
    super.onPeerDisconnected(node);
}
}
```

AndroidManifest on the wear side

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="laufnavigation.awp.hska.de.androidwearapp">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="false" />

    <activity android:name=".MainWearActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyWearableListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add a path prefix to you intent filter. In your case in the android manifest of your wearable:

```
 <service
    android:name=".MyWearableListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
        <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix:"/start_MainActivity" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Let me know if it works!